# Sending additional static parameter with jquery remote validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to send an extra parameter to the validation server side script. I have this code:

```
$("#edit_info").validate({
                debug: false,
              rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    //remote: "validate.php",
                    remote: { url:"validate.php", async:false },
                    data: {'cat_id':'34'}
                    /*data: {
                      cat_id: function () { return '34'; }
                    }*/
                },
```

But only the name gets sent. Any idea why?
Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you make `cat_id` a function instead? Like what you have commented out basically.

Comment: it's the same. Only the name is sent. I have no idea why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out what the problem was. data must be inside the remote tags...

```
$("#edit_info").validate({
            debug: false,
          rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                remote: { 
                    url:"validate.php", 
                    data: {'cat_id':'34'},
                    async:false 
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to send dynamic parameters, instead of static:

```
$("#edit_info").validate({
        debug: false,
      rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            remote: { 
                url:"validate.php", 
                data: {'cat_id':function(){return $('#otherelement').val()}},
                async:false 
            }
        },
```

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to pass the field name as a variable instead of a specific ID? $(this).val() didn't work.

Comment: it would be something like this:  $('otherelement[name=foo]').val()

Comment: #JoeGalind You saved my lot of time. Thanks